# How to optimize a query with select, row number and a lot of LIKE

Tags: optimization, postgresql-10

I try to find search rank of a product in today's product history records. For this I use 6 ILIKE and 2 inner join. I have indexed all columns but still so slow. It takes approximately 10 sec. to execute.   How can I increase the speed.  I'm currently using postgresql 10. Any advice would be grateful. SqlFiddle and sql is below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/718b5/1

```
select
   search_rank 
from
   (
      select
         row_number() OVER (
      order by
         marketplace_rank) as search_rank,
         cp.cr_product_id as cr_product_id 
      from
         cr_products cp 
         INNER JOIN
            cr_product_histories cph 
            on cph.cr_product_id = cp.cr_product_id 
            and cph.created_at > now()::date 
         INNER JOIN
            cr_product_names cpn 
            on cpn.cr_product_name_id = cph.cr_product_name_id 
      where
         cpn.cr_product_name ILIKE '%dsa%' 
         and cpn.cr_product_name ILIKE '%ghfg%' 
         and cpn.cr_product_name ILIKE '%gfhgf%' 
         and cpn.cr_product_name ILIKE '%terttre%' 
         and cpn.cr_product_name ILIKE '%trter%' 
         and cpn.cr_product_name ILIKE '%sfjkkjh%' 
      order by
         marketplace_rank asc
   )
   xyz 
where
   cr_product_id = 1 limit 1
```

Comment: What kind of index did you created? To use an index for `ILIKE '%dsa%' ` (or similar conditions) you need to use a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)

Comment: Remove ORDER BY from subquery - it makes no sense. If `cr_products.cr_product_id` is not unique, add proper ORDER BY to main query - LIMIT without it gives now one random record (if it matches the subquery ordering now - this is random). In the case where `cr_products.cr_product_id` is primary/unique, remove ORDER BY and LIMIT altogether.